# How to add my own PHP code in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

First of all i would like to say that i dont know little bit of Drupal. But i have a requirement that i should integrate a particular module (its not a drupal module) from one stand alone website to drupal site.

The module will get name and email id as a input from the user and the system will generate one key and send the key to user's provided email id. This module already has been implemented i just wanted to place it on drupal site. How should I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the module developers guide:
http://drupal.org/developing/modules

And the drupal "installing modules" pages:
http://drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes

You can also add code to "theme" your output by using template.php i theme directory:
http://drupal.org/node/173880