# Drupal 6.x sending different welcome emails to users based on roles

Tags: drupal

I'm pretty much entirely new to Drupal, and I'm working on a project where one of our goals is to send a different registration email to one group of users after they sign up. My thinking was to create a token that can be used in the email that will be determined by the user's role. I went into user.module and added in this.
    roles;

```
if($welcomer == 'Student Member'){
$copying = "SPECIAL EMAIL TEXT";
}
else{
$copying = "GENERAL EMAIL TEXT";
} ?>
```

then in the tokens section I set this up

```
<?php '!sendit' => $copying, ?>
```

So far if used, this does nothing, even the else statement fails to trigger. So my question is, how would I go about this? Is this the optimal way or is there an easier way to go about it?

Comment: You shouldn't hack the Drupal core, check this out for information on how to customize Drupal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13644975/1068167

Answer (score 0):

[Don't hack the Drupal core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) or when you update Drupal all of your code will be lost.

I don't have an environment to test in at the moment so this code is not tested but you want something like this:

```
function yourModuleName_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Add your own function to the array of submit callbacks
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourModuleName_user_register_submit';
}

function yourModuleName_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // I don't think this line is correct but don't have an environment to test in at the moment
    // Do a print_r here on $form_state['values'] and see where the user roles are stored
    $roles = $form_state['values']['roles'];

    if(in_array('Student Member', $roles) {
        // send student email here
    } elseif(in_array('Teacher Member', $roles) {
        // send teacher email here
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. How would I go about using this code you've written up? As I said, I really have nigh on no experience with drupal.

Comment: You will need to create your own custom module and put the code in there. There is a tutorial doing this here: http://drupal.org/node/361112 EDIT: Just realized your on Drupal 6, here is the correct tutorial: http://drupal.org/node/206753